# How enable modsecurity only one site? in edit .htaccess?

Tags: apache2, mod-security

nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/security2.conf

```
<IfModule security2_module>
        SecDataDir /var/cache/modsecurity
        IncludeOptional /etc/modsecurity/*.conf
        IncludeOptional /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/*.load
</IfModule>
```

i try in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleEngine On
</IfModule>
```

Error:
.htaccess: SecRuleEngine not allowed here

**i have hestia cp and i cant edit <VirtualHost file:**
*# DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE! CHANGES WILL BE LOST WHEN REBUILDING DOMAINS*

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ModSecurity on a per site basis with the `SecRuleEngine` directive in a VirtualHost definition of that site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com 
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ...
        SecRuleEngine On
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Regarding your edit that you're using a control panel:

> ### Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic
>
> because they [customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels). Some related topics may be asked on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or see [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels)

My guess is that setting custom non-standard settings in a Apache VirtualHost in Hestia requires creating a custom apache2 template with the correct settings and directives and then in the advanced options select that template instead of the default one.

Comment: i have hestia cp and i cant edit <VirtualHost file: 
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE! CHANGES WILL BE LOST WHEN REBUILDING DOMAINS. Lost changes

Comment: Repeating my last paragraph for your benefit: *"My guess is that setting custom non-standard settings in a Apache VirtualHost in Hestia requires creating a custom apache2 template with the correct settings and directives and then in the advanced options select that template instead of the default one."*

Comment: tanks is right way i think, but i copy default files to new names (/usr/local/hestia/data/templates/web/apache2) to new teample and not see him in list in control panel. Why?

Comment: tanks i copy defaylt files in /usr/local/hestia/data/templates/web/apache2/php-fpm and see it in list